# Why the output of this C code so

Tags: c

```
printf("%d %d",sizeof('a'),sizeof("a"))
```

This is giving output as 4 and 2. Why the output is so?

Answer (score 5):

In C a character constant has type `int`, thus 4 bytes in your case. When applied to a string literal (such as `"a"`), `sizeof` yields the number of bytes. Thus 2 (`'a'`, and `'\0'`).

Also, `%d` isn't the right specifier for printing `size_t`. You should probably be using `%zu` or `%zd`.

Answer (score 2):

The first one because `'a'` is a character (note single quotes) and considered an `int` type in C.

The second one because `"a"` is a string  (double quotes) consisting of two bytes, `'a'` and `'\0'`.